# $\mathbb{E}(\tau_B<\tau_A\mid X_0=B,X_1=A)=0 ?$

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Consider a discrete time Markov chain with state space $S =\left\{A, B, C, D, E \right\}$ and transition matrix
$$P= \left ( \begin{array}{c|ccccc}
 & A & B & C & D & E\\
\hline
A & 0 & 1/3 & 1/3 &1/3 &0 \\
B & 1/3 & 0 & 1/3 &0 &1/3\\
C & 1/2 & 1/2 & 0 &0 &0\\
D & 1/2 & 0 & 0 &0 &1/2\\
E & 0& 1/2 & 0 &1/2 &0\\
\end{array} \right )$$

What is the expected number of times passing through state $B$
before reaching state $A$, assuming you start from state $C$ ?
The hint only provides a system of linear recurrence equations including the following ：

$$\mathbb{E}(\tau_B<\tau_A\mid X_0=B)=1/3\cdot\mathbb{E}(\tau_B<\tau_A\mid X_0=B)+1/3\cdot\mathbb{E}(\tau_B<\tau_A\mid X_0=E),$$

where $\tau_{x}:=\inf\left\{n\in\mathbb{N}:X_n=x\right\},x\in S.$

---

I thought that
$\mathbb{E}(\tau_B<\tau_A\mid X_0=B)=P_{BA}\cdot\mathbb{E}(\tau_B<\tau_A\mid X_0=B,X_1=A)+P_{BB}\cdot\mathbb{E}(\tau_B<\tau_A\mid X_0=B,X_1=B)+P_{BC}\cdot\mathbb{E}(\tau_B<\tau_A\mid X_0=B,X_1=C)+P_{BD}\cdot\mathbb{E}(\tau_B<\tau_A\mid X_0=B,X_1=D)+P_{BE}\cdot\mathbb{E}(\tau_B<\tau_A\mid X_0=B,X_1=E).$

I don't why $\mathbb{E}(\tau_B<\tau_A\mid X_0=B,X_1=A)=0.$

Answer (score 1):

If $X_1=A$ then $\tau_A=1$. We cannot have $\tau_B<\tau_A(=1)$ since $\tau_B$ is a positive integer.

If you interpret $\mathbb N$ as $\{0,1,2...\}$ instead of $\{1,2...\}$ then the conditionl probability of $\tau_B<\tau_A$ given $X_0=B, X_1=A$ is $1$.

Comment: I always think $\tau_{B}=0$ in $\mathbb{E}(\tau_B<\tau_A\mid X_0=B,X_1=A)$,since $X_0=B.$ I don't know why it is a positive integer.

Comment: Look at the definition of $\tau_x$. I think  $\mathbb N$ is supposed to be $\{1,2,3...\}$ @user250236

Comment: Oops ! I have always mistakenly thought that $\mathbb{N}$ is shorthand for $\left\{0,1,2,...\right\}.$+1

Comment: If $\mathbb{N}:=\left\{0,1,2,...\right\},$ then $\mathbb{E}(\tau_B<\tau_A\mid X_0=B,X_1=A)\ne0.$

Comment: As far as I know, Analysts and Probalisits always define $\mathbb N$ as $\{1,2,3,...\}$ Algebraists have a tendency to include $0$ @user250236

Comment: The symbol $\mathbb N$ comes from 'Natural number' and here is the definition of natural numbers: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-are-natural-numbers/

Comment: When we talk about the hitting probability, This notion $\tau$ always used. Some of books say $\mathbb{N}:=\left\{0,1,2,...\right\},$ others gave $\mathbb{N}:=\left\{1,2,...\right\}.$

Comment: In that case, $\tau_B=0$ and $\tau_A=1$ (because $X_0=B\neq A$ and $X_1=A$) so your conditional probaility becomes $1$, not $0$.